# An Iteration for particular combinations on SAS

Tags: loops, iteration

The table below lists each possibility for each variable 'A', 'B' and 'C',  and the probability of that combination occurring.  I already know all the probabilities.

```
  Row #  |   A  |   B   |   C     |     Probability 
============================================================ 
    0    |  ...  |  ...  |   ...   |        P0
------------------------------------------------------------ 
    1    |  ...  |  ...  |   ...   |        P1
------------------------------------------------------------ 
    .    |  ...  |   .   |   .     |        .
------------------------------------------------------------ 
    .    |  ...  |   .   |   .     |        .
------------------------------------------------------------ 
    10   |  ...  |  ...  |   ...   |        P10 
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to write an iteration within a combination of variables 'A', 'B' and 'C':

```
start from Row = 0, keep increasing 
for Row = i. 
    If P(Row >= i) * 300 - P(Row < i) * 600 > 0 
        do 
            i = i+1; 
        until P(Row >= i) * 300 - P(Row < i) * 600 <= 0 or i =10.
```

It will stop and output i for a combination of 'A', 'B' and 'C'. And i is what I need for a combination of (A / B / C). Which is regarded as 'Threshold' in my problem.

How could I write this kind of code since there are many combinations of variables 'A', 'B' and 'C'.

Example:

When i = 0, P(Row >= 0) * 300 - P(Row < 0) * 600 = 1* 300 - 0* 600 = 300 > 0 Hence, i = 0+1 = 1

When i = 1, P(Row >= 1) * 300 - P(Row < 1) * 600 = 0.95* 300 - 0.05* 600 = 255 > 0   i = 1+1 = 2

When i = 2, P(Count >= 2) * 300 - P(Row < 2) * 600 = 0.85* 300 - 0.15* 600 = 165 > 0   i = 2+1 = 3

When i = 3, P(Row >= 3) * 300 - P(Row < 3) * 600 = 0.70* 300 - 0.30* 600 = 30 > 0     i = 3+1 = 4

When i = 4, P(Row >= 4) * 300 - P(Row < 4) * 600 = 0.50* 300 - 0.50* 600 = -150 < 0

we stop and output i =4 for this combination of 'A', 'B' and 'C'.

Thank you!

Comment: @MooingDuck I edited on my question, thanks! And what I need is the i (number of count) for each combination of 'A', 'B' and 'C', which is regarded as threshold number in my problem. And is there anyway to do it on SAS?

Comment: `P(Row >= i) * 300 - P(Row < i) * 600 > 0` is the same as `P(Row >= i) > 
2 * P(Row < i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Observing that `P(Row >= i) * 300 - P(Row < i) * 600 > 0` is the same as `P(Row >= i) > 2 * P(Row < i)`, we simply sum `P(Row<i)` until it's greater than half of the current element.

```
double sum = 0;
auto it = data.begin();
while(it != data.end() && *it > 2*sum) {
    sum += *it;
    ++it;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I know the logic now, and will then transfer to SAS